# Got a minus one from a read call

Tags: sql, oracle, putty

I connect to a database with read only access using SQL developer. It's a TNS connection. I use a tnsnames.ora, forwarding port script and SQL Developer.

In the past, occasionally, when connecting, I get a error message
Got a minus one from a read call.
Vendor Code 0

If I do a reboot, it goes away. Another friend suggested changed the forwarding port which worked for him.

I recently upgraded  to a new computer and now it seems that I am getting the error message consistently. Reboot or changing forwarding port does not help at all.

The port forwarding script contains something like this

```
putty -L (port):(machine name):1521
```

Does anybody have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My port forwarding script forwards multiple ports. Somehow separating them into 2 smaller file, this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sqlnet.ora file and comment if there is any entry like the below.

```
tcp.validnode_checking = yes

tcp.invited_nodes=(<hostname_1>, <hostname_2>)
```

Now reload your listener and check the connectivity from SQL Developer.

```
lsnrctl reload <SID>
```