# SQL Developer error: got minus one from a read call

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Question : I got the error: got minus one from a read call when I use SQL Developer.

Situation 
There are 4 computers to access DB. Their computer settings are same. Other three computers can access DB without error, but the computer got error, called 'got minus one from a read call' and 'connection reset'

Fact
1. This is not DB connection pool problem because it happens after computer A accesses AND before computer C accesses.
2. In sqlnet.ora, all of computers doesn't have parameter, called 'tcp.validnode_checking'

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can read this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824438/got-a-minus-one-from-a-read-call?rq=1]